# Shared library libgcrypt found in system python but not in Anaconda environment

Tags: arch-linux, python, shared-library

I'd like to use the `lxml.html` module in python3.5. When running my system python, I can do `import lxml.html` successfully. When I issue the same command in an Anaconda environment, I receive `ImportError: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Here's the list of installed packages in that environment (`conda list -n envname`):

bokeh                     0.12.3                   py35_0
jinja2                    2.8                      py35_1
libiconv                  1.14                          0
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0
libxslt                   1.1.29                        0
lxml                      3.7.0                    py35_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py35_2
mkl                       11.3.3                        0
numpy                     1.11.2                   py35_0
openssl                   1.0.2j                        0
pandas                    0.19.1              np111py35_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
python                    3.5.2                         0
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py35_0
pytz                      2016.10                  py35_0
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_0
readline                  6.2                           2
requests                  2.12.3                   py35_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py35_0
six                       1.10.0                   py35_0
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0
tk                        8.5.18                        0
tornado                   4.4.2                    py35_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
xz                        5.2.2                         0
yaml                      0.1.6                         0
zlib                      1.2.8                         3

I have the following packages installed via pacman: `python-lxml`, `libxml2`, `libxslt`. I'm running arch linux; the system is up to date.

If anything else is of interest, please let me know!

It seems that someone had [a similar issue before](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39664), but I don't quite understand the answer given there.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libgcrypt15` with `pacman` works for me.